# Content width (960 px or 940px)

Tags: pixel, screen-resolution

I´m having some difficulties deciding content width...

I´m going for 960 pixels using the stuff from the 960.gs (960 grid system)

Wich do you recommend?

A - 940 px width on the actual content with 10px margins on left and right side

or...

B - Get more out of the width and use full 960 px for the total content length

Which one is recommended or used in general?

Answer (score 2):

I would think this would depend heavily on your design. Generally speaking 960 seems to be the most commonly used but I think as long as you stay under 980 you'll probably be fine. 960 just lends itself well to easy math where 978 or 940 are a bit more complicated.

My experience has been that I've never received a design that naturally fits the 960 gs all that well and content width has been dictated by the design. The gs is a helpful guideline but not a rule.

Comment: May I ask why it has to stay under 980px? Based on statistics on screen resolution?

Comment: @gorn It can fit in 1080px minus system menus and browser chrome. I think 960px is the safe minimum even on vertical screens.